# How to get the next element after the .active class

Tags: css, class, css-selectors, listitem

[Trying to get next element after li.active class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fsF3p.png)

I am trying to get the next element **after the .active element** with css, the element that gets the .active class, is the first list-item of the '[Lightslider](http://sachinchoolur.github.io/lightslider/examples.html)'.

I've tried the code below:

```
.lslide.active +  li:nth-child(1) {
  -ms-transform: scale(1.3);
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.3);
  transform: scale(1.3);
}
```

Is this possible with only CSS?

Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just use the [adjacent sibling selector `+`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_selectors), you don't need the `nth-child` selector:

```css
.active + li {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="active">Item</li>
  <li>Item</li>
  <li>Item</li>
</ul>
```